# Where did the idea of a Pharaoh originate?

Tags: ancient-egypt

Before the unified Egypt there was a couple of places like Cheni, Nubut and Néjen and it is likely that Cheni's people gained the control of territory and from that moment on they occupied the area of Egypt. Also, according to "Faraones" by History Channel it is believed that Narmer is the first pharaoh. Even if Narmer came from Cheni, the idea of the pharaoh also came from there or is it product of several cultures?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Answer (score 1):

## Its Language

Pharaoh is the Term people use to refer to the leader or king of Egypt.  Pharoah is not that different from a king. The term Phaora is just pure language and not a "New Invention".